# Why is GCC not seeing functions in header file?

Tags: header-files, reference

When I try to compile I get this:

```
aero$ gcc hostinfo.c
/tmp/cc2RfYB2.o: In function `main':
hostinfo.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `Gethostbyaddr'
hostinfo.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `Gethostbyname'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

hostinfo.c looks like this:

```
/* $begin hostinfo */
#include "csapp.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

...

    if (inet_aton(argv[1], &addr) != 0)
        hostp = Gethostbyaddr((const char *)&addr, sizeof(addr), AF_INET);
    else
        hostp = Gethostbyname(argv[1]);

...

}
/* $end hostinfo */
```

And csapp.h looks like this:

```
/* $begin csapp.h */
#ifndef __CSAPP_H__
#define __CSAPP_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

...

/* DNS wrappers */
struct hostent *Gethostbyname(const char *name);
struct hostent *Gethostbyaddr(const char *addr, int len, int type);

... 

#endif /* __CSAPP_H__ */
/* $end csapp.h */
```

Both hostinfo.c and csapp.h are in the same directory. I'm new to Unix and gcc so I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: gcc sees the declarations, but where is the definition of those functions ? This is what the linker can't find.

Comment: Capitalization matters. Why are you supplying your own incorrectly-capitalized prototypes? Use the ones in the system header, and the linker will be able to find the corresponding symbols in the system libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile the file containing the implementation of these functions, and then link it with the calling file:

```
gcc -c csapp.c                      # This creates csapp.o
gcc -c hostinfo.c                   # This creates hostinfo.o
gcc -o hostinfo hostinfo.o csapp.o  # Link them together, creating executable hostinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

I was basically having the error of undefined reference to `function_name'

It was finally resolved by combining both the c files in the executable

For example, I had csv.c and columns.c with columns.h, so instead of

```
gcc csv.c -o csv
```

I used

```
gcc csv.c columns.c -o csv
```